# Request to reopen (or properly close) question 358637 (Hardware for a gaming PC)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I'd like to request to reopen this question:

> #### [How do I choose hardware for a gaming machine, and which components are the most important ones?](https://superuser.com/questions/358637/how-do-i-choose-hardware-for-a-gaming-machine-and-which-components-are-the-most)
>
> […]
>
> What I know is that I need a powerful graphics card and CPU, and for the most part, not much else, as games dont require a ton of RAM, Hard Drive space, etc. What I don't know is what constitutes a "powerful" graphics card and CPU.
>
> Basically what I need is for someone to explain what the different specs of computer components (mostly CPU, graphics card, and motherboard) mean, and which ones are important to a good gaming computer.
>
> Also, on a similar note, I am not sure how to choose a power supply that will support all the components that I ultimately buy. Is there a tool out there that I can use for this?

This is **not**:

- A specific "What hardware model should I buy?" buying recommendation.
- Too localized. There are plenty of people who run into the same issues and don't know where to start.
- Not constructive. I know we as a community can write great CW answers that are not "Buy a GeForce 12345 WhatEver™"

This is absolutely **the kind of question we encourage**. This is the exact opposite of the ones we close all the time.

Help people to help themselves. How do I find out what a good graphics card is? Which hardware is worth spending money on in a gaming rig? What kind of power supply do I need?

---

I know we have similar questions already, **at least close it as a duplicate** of those, not as off-topic. This is sending the wrong message.

Thanks @random for finding them.

- [How do we assemble a computer properly?](https://superuser.com/questions/297766/how-do-we-assemble-a-computer-properly)
- [Getting up to speed on modern PC construction](https://superuser.com/questions/74246/getting-up-to-speed-on-modern-pc-construction)
- [What should a person know before assembling their first computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/275194/what-should-a-person-know-before-assembling-their-first-computer)
- [How do I know what hardware to buy to meet my needs?](https://superuser.com/questions/297274/how-do-i-know-what-hardware-to-buy-to-meet-my-needs)
- [How to choose a UPS / calculate power for a new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was indeed a bevy of master questions on the subject. Even if they're not strictly about a gaming rig, the application still applies.

Reopened the question and reclosed as a duplicate of:

### [How do I know what hardware to buy to meet my needs?](https://superuser.com/questions/297274/how-do-i-know-what-hardware-to-buy-to-meet-my-needs)

Which should be a good jump start on what to look for and what to keep in mind about constructing a new machine for whatever purpose. In this case, eating Cheetos and drinking Fanta for eight hours straight.

Comment: Mmmhh, Cheetos.

Comment: or luridly coloured artificially flavoured junk food, washed down with the carbonated flavoured beverage of your preference ;p